# debuggin on an Iphone from Xamarin Ios Windows?

Tags: debugging, xamarin.ios

I am developping an Ios application with Xamarin.Ios under a windows pc connected with a Mc through network. I am juste wondering when I need to debug in a real device (Iphone) should I plug the device in the Mac or in the pc? Thank You

Comment: currently you need to connect the device to the Mac's USB

Answer (score 0):

You must to connect the device to Mac. But that's not all. You must setting up your device for development. It is [detail manual](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/).